# Synchronisation problem on a variation of the classic bounded buffer problem using java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, theory

I made a variation on the classic bounded buffer problem.

It's a LOT different and there is a small technical bump in the road I need to know for threadsafety ( rather than testing endlessly for a sitatuation that MAY never occur)

I don't really think I need to explain the situation it's about the evaluation of the following code sample

```
if(buffer1.BufferNotFull)
{
    buffer1.Lock();
    buffer1.AddValueAtIndex(value, index);
    buffer1.Unlock();
}
```

Basically my buffer1 has a simple condition variable (updated and all) that lets me know if it's not full and then I aquire a lock , do the magic, and release the lock.

But can I simply assume that evaluating the condition "is buffernotfull" can not interleave with another thread just writing over the LAST slot in my buffer?

(The buffer is actually an array of values with -1 representing empty, don't ask why ^_^)

In short: Is the evaluation of

```
if(buffer1.BufferNotFull)
```

threadsafe with the body code aquiring the lock

**EDIT**

This is the system I am now using for my entire system. I hope it helps in showing my design. Take into consideration I made this design purely for learning purposes of these basic synchronisation mechanisms.

**Control flow for the threads accesing the buffers**

Read Input Stream (No synchronisation required)

ATTEMPT:

1. Write operation from producer thread
   on buffer1 REQUEST LOCK:
2. If lock denied, keep requesting
   lock.
3. If condition variable is not met,
   wait
4. If lock accepted, perform write
   operation
5. unlock buffer1 and notify other
   waiting threads.
6. If input stream is empty and buffer1
   is die and request death from
   filterthread

ATTEMPT:

1. Read operation from the filter
   thread on buffer1 REQUEST LOCK:
2. If lock denied, keep requesting lock
3. If lock accepted, perform read
   operation (replace value with -1)
   and store the value in the thread
   after applying the filter.
4. If condition variable is not met,
   wait.
5. unlock buffer1 and notify other
   waiting threads.
6. If buffer1 and buffer2 are empty and
   a death request exists, die.

ATTEMPT:

1. Write operation from the filter
   thread on buffer2 REQUEST LOCK:
2. If lock denied, keep requesting lock
3. If lock accepted, perform write
       operation (with the filtered
       results).
4. If condition variable is not met,
   wait.
5. unlock buffer2 and notify other
   waiting threads.
6. If buffer1 and buffer2 are empty and
   a death request exists, send a death
   request to consumer thread and die.

ATTEMPT:

1. Read Operation on buffer2 from the
   consumer thread
2. If lock denied, keep requesting lock
3. If lock accepted, perform read
       operation (replace value with -1)
       and directly output the variable
       onto the console.
4. If condition variable is not met,
   wait.
5. Unlock buffer2 and notify other
   waiting threads.
6. If buffer2 is empty and a death
   request exists, die.

**Control flow for the individual thread operations**

Get lock
Check condition variable
If YES,  write/read operation
If NO, wait for notfiy
Unlock

I will build and test the last part of the implementation and edit to see if the accepted answer really did get me results but that could take a bit of time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, in the above scenario, you have to first acquire the lock, and then test for the condition to be true:

```
buffer1.Lock();

try {

    while( !buffer1.BufferNotFull ) {

          buffer1.WaitOnConditionVariable();
    }

    buffer1.AddElement(...);

} finally {

    buffer1.Unlock();
}
```

Any other order to the operations imposes the risk of a "time-of-check/time-of-use" race condition: consider the scenario, where the current thread is preempted right after checking the status with `BufferNotFull` but before grabbing the lock. If the new thread adds a new element to the buffer, the buffer's state may become "full" again. When the original thread resumes, it will thus trigger a "buffer full" exception (or whatever) when trying to add its own new element, even though it properly did check (from its own point of view).

**Edit** The condition variable will release the lock before it actually goes into hibernation during the "wait" operation. This is done atomically, i.e., the thread is going to sleep "in the same instant" as the lock is being released. When the variable is notified by some other thread, it will re-acquire the lock before it resumes execution after the call to "WaitOnConditionVariable".

Code removing elements from the buffer might look like this:

```
buffer1.Lock();

try {

    if( !buffer.IsEmpty ) { 

         ... remove element ...
         BufferNotFull = true;
         NotifyConditionVariable();
    }
} finally {
    buffer1.Unlock();
}
```

Or, to make it actually look like Java:

```
Object monitor = new Object();
boolean full = false;
boolean empty = true;
```

Adding elements:

```
synchronized( monitor ) {
    while( full ) {
        monitor.wait();
    }

    ... add element ...
    ... maybe set full ...
    empty = false;
    monitor.notifyAll();
}
```

Removing elements:

```
synchronized( monitor ) {
    while( empty ) monitor.wait();

    ... remove element ...
    ... maybe set empty ...
    full = false;
    monitor.notifyAll();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe this should solve the problem! The order in which I solved the problem was the problem! Let me just test it

Comment: If you keep checking the condition changes during a locked state. How can you expect a change? If the buffer is filled during the evaluation of the (IsBufferFull) condition and it's considered true the while loop just keeps checking an immutable variable right? Do I need to use wait/notify for this part?

Comment: I understand that the evaluation of the buffer state from the point of view from the thread does not take into consideration the state multithreading concept in which things change outside the flow of it's own scope. Thank you for that, just leaves me with question posted in comment2 about the while loop here.

Comment: This should do it , definitely gives me enough information to work with and answers the question of my second comment which simply keeps the thread pending for a notify. Thanks again!